# How to create a random value list with specific length with each value at least once within the range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a random value list with specific length with each value at least once  within a range using Python. Below is my Python code:

```
import random

Start = 1
Stop = 5
limit = 6

RandomListOfIntegers = [random.randint(Start, Stop) for iter in range(limit)]
print(RandomListOfIntegers)
```

I got an output list at one run as below:

```
[1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```

In the above output within start and stop range (1-5) 3 is missing. But I want the list with each value at least once within the range. My expected output as below:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```

Guide me to get the above output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming limit is greater than the range from start to stop how about creating a list with [start, start+1, ..., stop], adding however many more you need, then shuffling the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all the numbers, shuffle what you generated then add random number to reach the `limit`:

```py
import random

Start = 1
Stop = 5
limit = 6
RandomListOfIntegers = list(range(Start, Stop+1))
random.shuffle(RandomListOfIntegers)
RandomListOfIntegers.extend(random.choices(RandomListOfIntegers, k=limit-Stop))
print(RandomListOfIntegers)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I got my expected output as per your suggested code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do it in two steps

- sample the range, with its length, you'll get all the numbers of the interval in random order
- extend with random number until you reach the `limit`

```
randomListOfIntegers = random.sample(range(start, stop + 1), stop) + \
                       [random.randint(start, stop) for iter in range(limit - stop)]
```

---

You can also, generate all the values and shuffle them, then add elements to reach the `limit`

```
allValues = list(range(start, stop + 1))
random.shuffle(allValues)
randomListOfIntegers = allValues + [random.randint(start, stop) for iter in range(limit - stop)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I got my expected output as per your suggested code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to create a list with all the numbers, add extra and then shuffle, like this:

```
import random

Start=1
Stop=5
Limit=6

mylist = list(range(Start,Stop+1))
for i in range(Limit-(Stop-Start)-1):
    mylist.append(random.randint(Start,Stop))
random.shuffle(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

it outputs:

```
[3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This `mylist = [Start:Stop]` doesn't exist;

Comment: @Gamopo: Thank you very much for your guidance. I got my expected output as per your suggested code. Thanks.